# How UserControl can tell when it's visible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a UserControl as below in my MainWindow:

```
<ctrls:Login Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Vis,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                          AncestorType=Window}},
                          Converter={StaticResource BooelanToVisibilityConverter}"/>
```

so it has it's visibility bound to a property Vis in the MainWindow's ViewModel.

What I am wondering is, inside the UserControl's ViewModel how can I pickup when the visibility has changed? I would like to start a timer when visible and stop it when hidden.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can hook **[UIElement.IsVisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** event on userControl:

```
<ctrls:Login IsVisibleChanged="Control_VisibleChanged"/>
```

**Code behind:**

```
private void Control_VisibleChanged(object sender, 
                                        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
       // Visible code here
    }
    else
    { 
       // Collapse code here
    }
 }
```

If you want to start `Timer`, i see no issue in doing that from code behind.

But, however if you still want that to be notified in ViewModel you can **create an `ICommand` in UserControl ViewModel and bind to this event using `interaction triggers`**:

```
<ctrls:Login>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="IsVisibleChanged">
          <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding VisibleChangedCommand}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ctrls:Login>
```

You can refer to this article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57664/Silverlight-and-WPF-Behaviours-and-Triggers-Unders) in case interaction triggers is something new for you.

Comment: He want to be notified in the viewmodel, not in the control's code-behind

Comment: `e.NewValue` is a bool and not of type Visibility. Your code should show `if ((bool)e.NewValue) { // IsVisible code here} ...`

Comment: @RohitVats I tried implementing this both ways and I have understood the first, however I am having problems with the ICommand in the user control view model second example, do you have an example of this working please?

Comment: You need to refer to `Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core` dll in your project to use it. Refer to the sample [here](http://coreclr.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/using-interaction-triggers-in-mvvm/) and [here](http://www.danharman.net/2011/08/05/binding-wpf-events-to-mvvm-viewmodel-commands/) OR simply search on google using interaction triggers MVVM, you'll get lots of references there.

Comment: This wont work because IsVisibleChanged is a CLR event, this has allready been answered in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497449/mvvm-binding-to-clr-events
and:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819812/using-interaction-trigger-to-call-visibility-changed-method-wpf