# C# mvvm binding events onto RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, richtextbox

I found multiple solutions how to use RichTextBox with dragAndDrop events, but only if i place methods into View .cs file. Im curious if this is possible via MVVM, binding and placing code into ViewModel.

So i have simple RichTextBox where im trying to bind events from view model

```
<RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="280" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,10,10"
                 PreviewDragEnter="{Binding RTBPreviewDragEnter}"
                 PreviewDragOver="{Binding RTBPreviewDragEnter}"
                 PreviewDrop="{Binding RTBPreviewDrop}"
                 >

        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

And ViewModel

```
 private Boolean IsFileImage(string fileName)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void RTBPreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            if (files != null && files.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("preview drop");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

    }

    public void RTBPreviewDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

        if (files != null && files.Length > 0 && files.Where(IsFileImage).Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("preview drag enter");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

And when i try to run this, it throws exception that
**binding cannot be set on property AddPreviewDragEnterHandler of type RichTextBox and that i should use DependencyProperty on DependencyObject**

Is there posibility to bind events on RichTextBox via MVVM without Dependency? (i read somewhere that Dependency isnt good idea with MVVM)

Also i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497449/mvvm-binding-to-clr-events) question here, which is same, but its using Expression Blend SDK. Is it good point to use it?

Or which approach is good one in MVVM?

Edit:
This question was marked as dupliace, but in other question author accepting solution achieved via Expression Blend SDK, but i was just curious if it can be done without it.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874425/Drag-and-Drop-in-MVVM-WPF

I found the above attached behaviour to be really good. I had to study it a bit to figure out how it worked, but it was well worth it (you can download a sample project). I find it to be really dynamic and clean, and perfect for an MVVM approach.

It's also quite scalable; there's a lot of scope for enhancements, modifications, customisations, etc. For example, my current version has an attached property of `CanDropLogic`:

```
delegate bool CanDropLogic(UIElement DropTarget, Point CurrentPosition, Window TopWindow);
```

This allows me to dynamically provide the behaviour with further logic if my `DropTarget` is something like a `ListBox`, and I only want to be able to drop onto items matching a certain criteria.